# Using array variables in page filter

Tags: twig, octobercms

This is the code

```
<a href="{{ 'questions' | page({Filter[search] : 1}) }}">{{category.name}}</a>
```

It should generate an URL like

> http://localhost/vos-questions?Filter[search]=1&Filter[categories]=3&Filter[sort]=published_at+desc

but is not working! if I try to use `'Filter[search]' : 1` instead, the URL is generated but without the Filter params.

The destination page ('questions') is defined with a :page param, the Filter params are not defined.

```
title = "questions"
url = "/vos-questions/:page?"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm it will not work

your url is like this `url = "/vos-questions/:page?"` so `page` must be the argument and it will be consider like this

```
/vos-questions/test => now in code `page` param's value will be `test`
```

if you really need that url then there is better solution.

```
// question page 
title = "questions"
url = "/vos-questions" <- we remove param here as we pass it manually


// now html code
<a href="{{'questions'|page }}?Filter[search]=1&Filter[categories]=3&
                    Filter[sort]=published_at+desc">{{category.name}}</a>
```

it should work as expected it will generate url  like this

> http://localhost/vos-questions/?Filter[search]=1&Filter[categories]=3&Filter[sort]=published_at+desc

and if you want to pass dynamic values you can also do like this

```
// suppose $search = 2 in code and $cat = 30

<a href="{{'questions'|page }}?Filter[search]={{ search }}
                          &Filter[categories]={{ cat }}
                    &Filter[sort]=published_at+desc">{{category.name}}</a>
```

so generated url will be

> http://localhost/vos-questions/?Filter[search]=2&Filter[categories]=30&Filter[sort]=published_at+desc

now in code you can get this values using `Input`

https://octobercms.com/docs/services/request-input

```
$filter = \Input::get('Filter');
echo $filter['categories']; // => 30
```

if  any doubts please comment.

Comment: It works! I don't know if this is the 'canonical' way of solving it but it does the work.

Comment: no its not the `canonical` way but for large amount of filters you need to do this, for small set you can do like `/vos-questions/:search/:category/:sort` and manually pass 3 param using `{{ 'questions' | page({search : 1, 'category': ...}) }}` but its good for only short data